# How Filter Platform Events with LWC?

Tags: salesforce, apex, lwc

I have a lwc component that subscribes to the event WhatsAppMessage, and I have been trying to filter the event platform but I have not been able to get the expected result, since it does not respect my filter and it brings me all the results

[image]

This is my JS Code when I suscribe

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 
'lightning/empApi';

export default class PlatformEventMonitor extends LightningElement {
channelName = '/event/Sample__e';
isSubscribeDisabled = false;
isUnsubscribeDisabled = !this.isSubscribeDisabled;

subscription = {};

// Tracks changes to channelName text field
handleChannelName(event) {
    this.channelName = event.target.value;
}

// Initializes the component
connectedCallback() {       
    // Register error listener       
    this.registerErrorListener();      
}

// Handles subscribe button click
handleSubscribe() {
    // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
    const messageCallback = function(response) {
        console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        // Response contains the payload of the new message received
    };

    // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
        // Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
        console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
        this.subscription = response;
        this.toggleSubscribeButton(true);
    });
}

// Handles unsubscribe button click
handleUnsubscribe() {
    this.toggleSubscribeButton(false);

    // Invoke unsubscribe method of empApi
    unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
        console.log('unsubscribe() response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
        // Response is true for successful unsubscribe
    });
}

toggleSubscribeButton(enableSubscribe) {
    this.isSubscribeDisabled = enableSubscribe;
    this.isUnsubscribeDisabled = !enableSubscribe;
}

registerErrorListener() {
    // Invoke onError empApi method
    onError(error => {
        console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
        // Error contains the server-side error
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think this would work? I don't recognise syntax for filtering like that? From what doc you took it?

You can set replay id to -1, -2 but you'll get all messages. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation

You can filter them out manually in your app but it'll waste the daily limit of the events to can receive...

The proper way would be to define custom channel on top of your event. It's bit like writing a query/listview/report. But there is no UI for it, you'd have to craft a special JSON and send it to ord using tooling API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_filter_section.htm